# Making one list that satisfies the condition

Tags: python, list, if-statement, comparison

I have a CSV file containing the following data:

```
1,1,3,2,2,1
2,1,3,2,1,1
3,2,4,2,7,3
4,1,3,2,3,1
5,3,3,1,1,1
```

and I would like to create a list that has the elements of sixth column which has 1 for second column. In short, the end result I would like is `[1, 1, 1]`

Here is the code I wrote:

```
input = open("C:\\test.txt", "r")

for line in input.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    no, grade, gpa, sex, preview, review = line.split(',')

    listno1 = []
    a = float(grade)
    if a == 1:
        listno1.append(int(review))
```

When I print, it turns out like this:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[1]
[2]
[]
[]
[4]
[]
```

Help please? And I would kind of like to stick to using lists.

Comment: You have `listno1 = []` inside the loop, so you're clearing it every time through.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating your list for each row, rather than create the list just once outside the loop.

You are also reinventing the CSV wheel; use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) instead. Because you are picking just the one column for each row where a condition is met, you can use a list comprehension:

```
import csv

with open("C:\\test.txt", "r") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    listno1 = [int(row[5]) for row in reader if int(row[1]) == 1]
```

This basically does the same thing as:

```
import csv

with open("C:\\test.txt", "r") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    listno1 = []
    for no, grade, gpa, sex, preview, review in reader:
        grade = int(grade)
        if grade == 1:
            listno1.append(int(review))
```

but in more compact notation.

Comment: more compact to use  `if grade == "1"` without casting to an int